# Android Emulator internet connectivity issue

Tags: android, android-emulator, connectivity, zscaler

We're using the Zscaler application for security purpose. After the Zscaler installation, we're unable to use our Android emulators. Emulators are not connecting to the internet.

I've already tried the below suggestion.

try launching the emulator from the command line using the option -dns-server “2001:4860:4860::8844,2001:4860:4860::8888,8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4” .

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.